# How to remove a struct element from a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I'm a newbie programmer and I'm working on a program that holds a registry of pets in a hotel (some silly exercise we saw in class, doesn't matter). I'm using vectors for holding the struct elements (pets). The code for the struct is this:

```
struct Pets{
string Name;
string Race;
string Owner;
int Tel;
}p;
```

And the function to ask for user input is this:

```
AddPet(vector<Pets> &vtnew)
{
Pets newpet;
cout << "Enter the pet's name: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Name;
cout << "Enter the pet's race: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Race;
cout << "Enter the owner's name: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Owner;
cout << "Enter the owner's telephone number: " << endl;
cin >> newpet.Tel;
vtnew.push_back(newpet);
}
```

Ok, now I need to create a function to remove the pet by entering the name or something. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You should read an introduction book on C++ first.

Comment: You added them with a `std::vector` function: `push_back()`. Look into what other `std::vector` functions there are that might allow you to remove an item!

Comment: If your program wants to use the pet's name as a key to find the related `Pets` structure, it's more natural to use a `std::map<std::string, Pets>` instead of a `vector` - you then add pets using `vtnew[newpet.Name] = newpet;` (might want to change the `vtnew` variable name to be more descriptive) and erase with `vtnew.erase(some_pet_name);`.

Comment: @TonyD: No, that's not the correct container. `map` is for external keys, `set` is for internal keys. However, you'd need to provide your own `OrderPetsByName` comparison function.

Comment: @MSalters: `set<>`'s more memory efficient, but given Dave's getting started here, using a `map` is more convenient and quite functional.  (Or perhaps `multimap` if the names aren't guaranteed unique).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A vector is an unsorted container so the simple solutions are really your only choice.

```
void RemovePet(std::vector<Pet> & pets, std::string name) {
    pets.erase(
        std::remove_if(pets.begin(), pets.end(), [&](Pet const & pet) {
            return pet.Name == name;
        }),
        pets.end());
}
```

This is known as the [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Note that this will remove all pets matching that name, not just one.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry, what exactly is pets? Is it the name of the struct or the object? Thank you

Comment: @DaveCarballo: It's right in the function prototype: `std::vector<Pet> & pets`

Comment: excuse me, how do I call the function later? which parameters should I use?

Comment: @DaveCarballo: `RemovePet(vtnew, "Fluffy");`, then the caller's `vector` variable - known as `vtnew` (or whatever better name you change it to), will be referenced by `pets` inside `RemovePet`.