# Removing struct from list based on id

Tags: c++, list, struct

I have created a function to do this:

```
void Server::removeClient(unsigned short value) {
    std::list<Client>::iterator itri = clients.begin();
    while (itri != clients.end()) {
        if (itri->id == value) {
            itri = clients.erase(itri);
        } else {
            ++itri;
        }
    }
}
```

but get the error:

> list iterator not incrementable

I've been looking on similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167082/c-list-iterator-not-incrementable) that says I should not increment my iterator after I call erase, telling the asker they should put their iterator increment in an else statement which I have.

And I know that this kind of question has been asked a lot but I'm really baffled here.

Here are the full documents:

[Server.h](http://pastebin.com/eChQu6fd)

[Server.cpp](http://pastebin.com/yMTLeHeV)

Note for my C++ file, I copy-pasted mpiatek's question link answer to make extra sure that my code was right. Neither the commented out code or the current code work.

I also tried a remove_if, suggested by user4581301:

```
clients.erase(
    std::remove_if(clients.begin(), clients.end(), [&](Client const & c) {
    return c.id == value;
}),
    clients.end());
```

I got the code from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062126/how-to-remove-a-struct-element-from-a-vector) It doesn't work and returns the same error.

Comment: No to the duplicate. OP is trying to do this correctly, and [I'm unable to reproduce](http://ideone.com/WCKJvq). [mcve], please? Also consider using `std::remove_if` instead as part of the erase/remove idiom.

Comment: I've added the full files to my question. Could it be that it's because my list isn't a list of struct pointers?

Comment: @hvd  I agree, bad call. Removed that comment.

Comment: Tried using `std::remove_if`. Didn't work, added to question.

Comment: What you have provided is not minimum or complete. You have a bug somewhere, and it is not in the removal. You may have trashed the `list` somewhere. You may be calling the remove from another thread while the list is being iterated elsewhere. Too many open possibilities.

Comment: I have provided almost all my code. The only thing I have left out is the main.cpp, which literally just calls the constructor of Server.

Comment: I recommend working on minimum over complete in your case. Reduce the size of the area you have to search for the bug enough, and the bug will stare you in the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is not in the code you have shown, but in the calling function.

You call your removeClient in this code:

```
   for (Client &c : clients) {
        c.timeSinceLastPacket+= dt;
        if (c.timeSinceLastPacket.asSeconds() > 10) {
            std::cout << c.id << " has timed out!" << std::endl;
            removeClient(c.id);
        }
    }
```

Once `removeClient` has done its job, the (hidden) iterator that your for loop is using is then invalidated and the for loop can't continue.

You might be better off just using an iterator in the outer loop and removing via the iterator, rather than finding by ID again.

Even better use something like `std:remove_if` as was suggested in the comments

Comment: Thanks! I'll just call `break;` after calling my function.